# How can I require and exclude specific terms in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have three data frames:

1. An input set of words & phrases ("input")
2. A require set of words ("require")
3. An exclude set of words ("exclude")

They are all data frames.

**input**

```
      kw
1 baseball
2 football
3 tennis
4 basketball
5 basket ball
6 volleyball
7 base ball
8 women's golf
9 men's golf
10 golfing
```

**require**

```
    kw
1 ball
2 golf
```

**exclude**

```
  kw
1 basket
2 volley
```

I want the output to be:

```
      kw
1 baseball
2 football
3 base ball
4 women's golf
5 mens golf
6 golfing
```

How do I write this in R? When I use grep, I'm repeating the code over and over again. This should be easy to iterate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine two grep statements. For example

```
subset(dd, grepl("ball|golf",kw) & !grepl("basket|volley", kw))
```

works with the sample input

```
dd<-read.table(text="kw
baseball
football
tennis
basketball
basket ball
volleyball
base ball
women's golf
men's golf
golfing", sep="\t", quote="", header=T)
```

Comment: thank you MrFlick. I'm pulling in the dataframes from a .csv file. How do I combine them into the grep statements?

Comment: I would guess `paste(require$kw, collapse="|")`. Just be aware that grep requires a valid regular expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. When I type: **final = subset(input, grepl(paste(require$kw, collapse = "|")) & !grepl(paste(exclude$kw, collapse = "|")))** I get the following error message: **Error in grepl(paste(require$kw, collapse = "|")) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default**

Comment: You didn't pass the `kw` column to the `grepl` function. You only passed a pattern.  Take a closer look at my example.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick as always!